# How do I split a string by a delimiter into its own column of an HTML table on the same row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form with a text area where the user can paste in rows of data. The `generateTable` function takes the data from the text area and manipulates it such that it will generate an HTML table just below the text area. Easy enough.

I have complicated things by adding the string length to the original string on each row pasted into the text area and appended it with a ‘;’ to each row before it is inserted into the table in the DOM.

So if you paste or type in a row like “value1”, submit will render “value1; 6” to the first row of the table. Likewise, if the second row in the text area contains “value 2”, submit will render “value 2; 7” to the second row of the table.

My issue is that I want to split the new value at the semicolon and render each side of the string to its own cell on the same row. I’m stumped on this one and every attempt I make to do this turns into some pretty confusing spaghetti.

What’s the best approach to render each side of the semicolon to its own cell on the same row – “value1” in the first column, “6” in the second column?

I understand how to split the string. Rendering each to its own column in the table is my challenge.

```
// Get data inserted into the textarea and put in table below it //

// Create an array of the row values from the form
        function generateTable() {
            var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
            var rows = data.split("\n");
            var rowCount = rows.length;
            var newArray = [];
                for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
                var newRow = rows[i] + "; " + rows[i].length;

                var newRowString = JSON.stringify(newRow);

                newArray.push(newRow);

                }

// Build the table    
            var table = $('<table />');

            for (var y in newArray) {
                var cells = newArray[y].split("\t");
                var row = $('<tr />');
                for (var x in cells) {
                    row.append('<td>' + cells[x] + '</td>');
                }
                table.append(row);
            }

// Insert into DOM
            $('#excel_table').html(table);
        }
```

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
// Build the table    
        var table = $('<table />');

        for (var y in newArray) {
            var cells = newArray[y].split("\t");
            var row = $('<tr />');
            for (var x in cells) {
                row.append('<td>' + cells[x].split(";")[0] + '</td>');
                row.append('<td>' + cells[x].split(";")[1] + '</td>');
            }
            table.append(row);
        }
```

Comment: This answer is the simplest and most direct solution. Thanks @SriAji. I knew I was overthinking things.

Comment: my plesure :) @ToddBrannon

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
function add() {
  let v = data.value;
  data.value='';
  out.innerHTML+="<tr>"+v.split(';').map(x=>`<td>${x}</td>`).join('')+"</tr>"
}
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<textarea id="data" ></textarea>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="out">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```